# Why is Python's datetime difference returning the the wrong value?

Tags: python, datetime

I've been using the datetime module to create datetime objects from two input strings.

I'm trying to simply calculate the time difference between **1:00 PM** and **10:00 AM**, which should be 3 hours, not 15 hours, as I'm getting below.

What am I doing wrong?

```
In [29]: time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('10:00AM', '%H:%M%p')

In [30]: time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('1:00PM', '%H:%M%p')

In [31]: print time2 - time1
-1 day, 15:00:00
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

print the respective datetimes for a clue. You need the proper formatter with AM / PM.

```
>>> time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("10:00AM", "%I:%M%p")
>>> time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('1:00PM', '%I:%M%p')
>>> print time2 - time1
3:00:00
```

Comment: To clarify, `%H` does a 24-hour clock conversion, while `%I` uses a 12-hour clock.